# How can I get my mediawiki to stop thinking I have cookies disabled?

Tags: linux, php, php.ini, mediawiki

I've searched half a day for how to resolve this issue, and can't figure it out.  Shortly after I made my wiki a simple private wiki according to the instructions at Mediawiki's website, it started giving me this weird login error message:  *Wiki uses cookies to log in users. You have cookies disabled. Please enable them and try again.*

If I remove those private wiki settings, the error disappears, even if I try logging in.  But I need it to be a private wiki for only my team.  So what do I do?

Here's what I've done so far.  Just to be safe, after ever change, I try rebooting Apache using:

- sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

In my php.ini file, I have the following set:

- session.save_path = "/var/lib/php5"
- session.cookie_secure = secure
- session.cookie_path = /tmp session.cookie_domain = my server's internal URL (should I even set this?  this field was blank before, but not commented out)
- session.referer_check = Off

I ran the following to ensure that the folders are writable:

- sudo chmod -R 1777 /var/lib/php5
- sudo chmod -R 1777 /tmp

In my LocalSettings.php file, I have the following added to the bottom of the settings file:

- session_save_path("tmp");
- $wgSessionsInObjectCache = true;
- $wgMainCacheType = CACHE_ANYTHING;
- $wgDebugToolbar = true;
- $wgDebugLogFile='/var/log/mediawiki/mediawiki.log';
- $wgShowExceptionDetails = true;
- $wgShowDebug = true;
- $wgDevelopmentWarnings = true;

For the above tmp, I created the folder /etc/mediawiki/tmp and also ran the following:

- sudo chmod -R 1777 /etc/mediawiki/tmp

I know that the cookie is coming through to the browser because I can see the cookie in Firebug and verify that the same cookie got created in the /tmp folder.

SSL seems to be configured properly, because I get the green lock.

This is my debug output after trying to log in:

> **Debug data:**
>
> - Start request
> - POST /mediawiki/index.php?title=Special:UserLogin&action=submitlogin&type=login&returnto=Special:RecentChanges
> - HTTP HEADERS:
> - HOST: bs-wiki.sis.org.cn
> - CONNECTION: keep-alive
> - CONTENT-LENGTH: 122
> - CACHE-CONTROL: max-age=0
> - ACCEPT: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
> - ORIGIN: https://bs-wiki.sis.org.cn
> - UPGRADE-INSECURE-REQUESTS: 1
> - USER-AGENT: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.97 Safari/537.36
> - CONTENT-TYPE: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> - DNT: 1
> - REFERER: https://bs-wiki.sis.org.cn/mediawiki/index.php?title=Special:UserLogin&returnto=Special%3ARecentChanges&returntoquery=
> - ACCEPT-ENCODING: gzip, deflate
> - ACCEPT-LANGUAGE: en-US,en;q=0.8
> - COOKIE: __gads=ID=f46767e352615a06:T=1453974579:S=ALNI_MaImAtsIj8Xb-3kERZtmSWx82DxNA; bs_wikiUserName=Rpark1; bs_wikiLoggedOut=20160128105049; bs_wiki_session=3fck92pn1uq1l1s852oq6rfdl3
> - CACHES: SqlBagOStuff[main] SqlBagOStuff[message] SqlBagOStuff[parser]
> - Connecting to localhost bs_wiki...
> - Profiler::instance called without $wgProfiler['class'] set, falling back to ProfilerStub for safety
> - Connected to localhost bs_wiki.
> - Connecting to localhost bs_wiki...
> - Connected to localhost bs_wiki.
> - DatabaseBase::query: Writes done: DELETE FROM `objectcache` WHERE keyname = 'bs_wiki:stats:request_with_session'
> - LocalisationCache: using store LCStore_DB
> - Unstubbing $wgParser on call of $wgParser::setFunctionHook from unknown
> - Parser: using preprocessor: Preprocessor_DOM
> - Fully initialised
> - Unstubbing $wgAuth on call of $wgAuth::validDomain from unknown
> - IP: 172.18.12.59
> - MessageCache::load: Loading en... got from global cache
> - Unstubbing $wgLang on call of $wgLang::_unstub from unknown
> - MWCryptRand::realGenerate: Generating cryptographic random bytes for LoginForm::setLoginToken/MWCryptRand::generateHex/MWCryptRand::realGenerateHex/MWCryptRand::generate/MWCryptRand::realGenerate
> - MWCryptRand::realGenerate: openssl_random_pseudo_bytes generated 16
>     bytes of strong randomness.
> - MWCryptRand::realGenerate: 0 bytes of
>     randomness leftover in the buffer.
> - Class SkinVector not found; skipped loading
> - Class PEAR_Error not found; skipped loading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No idea why it works now, but started from scratch and went back to the original instructions at https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Preventing_access#Simple_private_wiki and now it works.

Well, not completely from scratch, I didn't revert my changes to php.ini.  So not sure whether or not that fixed it.  Either way, it's working now, and so I'm happy....  :)

Answer (score 1):

Basd82 elsewhere reports that you have to set `session.referer_check = Off` in php.ini.

`session_save_path("tmp")` is surely wrong, your directory is called `/tmp`. (If you followed [JesseG17's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16133328), you forgot step 3.) However, with `$wgSessionsInObjectCache = true` the `session.save_path` should be irrelevant.

You have `$wgMainCacheType = CACHE_ANYTHING`, but did you check that the cache actually works? Follow the [cache manual](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Cache) and install appropriate object caching (that's always a good idea).

Comment: Sad to say that I started from scratch and went back to the original instructions at https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Preventing_access#Simple_private_wiki .  Nothing changed from the first time I tried it, but it's working now.  No idea why, guess don't care either....  :)  Sorry, can't provide feedback on whether your advice worked or not.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem - here the server had run out of disk space. Clearing up some space did the trick.